# Is the initializer for a const static data member considered a default member initializer?

Tags: c++, static-members, in-class-initialization

Is the initializer for a `const` `static` data member considered a default member initializer?

The relevant wording is [[class.mem.general]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#10):

> A brace-or-equal-initializer shall appear only in the declaration of a
> data member. (For static data members, see [class.static.data]; for
> non-static data members, see [class.base.init] and [dcl.init.aggr]). A
> brace-or-equal-initializer for a **non-static** data member specifies
> a *default member initializer* for the member [..]

So for example:

```
constexpr int f() { return 0; }

struct A {
  static const int I = f();
};
```

Is the *brace-or-equal-initializer* `f()` considered a default member initializer?

Comment: you bolded that part that says "non-static". Isnt that clear?

Comment: No, it says so right in your quote: *A brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static data member specifies a default member initializer for the member*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Static data members aren't initialised in constructors. `f()` is just the initialiser for `A::I`.

A *default member initialiser* is used to initialise a non-static data member in each constructor where the [*mem-initializer-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.init#nt:mem-initializer-list) doesn't otherwise initialise that member. That is, it's a *default* for the *initialiser*s of that *member*.

[`[class.base.init#9]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.base.init#9)